# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2e^{-4x}-4y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I assume I rewrite the equation like this:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2e^{-4x}-4y \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}+4y=x^2e^{-4x}$

I then solve the homogenous form of the equation by writing its characteristic equation:

$r+4=0$, which means $r=-4$

This means my general solution is: $y=Ae^{-4x}$

But from here I don't know how to solve with RHS.

Comment: Integrate by parts a few times this is separable.

Comment: I don't understand your implication.  The answer, pretty clearly, is of the form $(Ax^2+Bx+C)e^{-4x}$ so you can just solve for $A,B,C$.

Comment: You rewrite the equaltion as $y'+4y=x^2e^{-4x}$. How do you do that?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout I'm sorry, I left out a term

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Assume that you have a solution of the form $A(x)e^{-4x}$ for the non-homogenuous problem $y'+4y=x^2e^{-4x}$ and substitute to this equation to get $A(x)$. The general solution of the ODE is $Ae^{-4x}+A(x)e^{-4x}.$

Edit. (methodology) A standard procedure goes like that: suppose you have found the general solution for the homogenuous equation $y'+f(x)y=0$, say $A ~y_{o}(x)$ (the way you did above). According to the general theory, the general solution of the equation $y'+f(x)y=g$ is of the form $A y_{o}(x)+y_p(x)$ where $y_p$ is a partial solution of the problem
$y'+f(x)y=g$. If you assume (this part might seem to be a bit strange) 
a partial solution of the form $A(x)~y_o(x)$, then by substitution you can get a diferrential equation for $A(x)$ and therefore a partial solution $y_p(x)$ (note you that you only need A partial solution: if you find one by trial and error
, of if you "assume" one and this leads you somewhere, it is enough!).

Comment: I don't understand how you got the second term in the general solution.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2e^{-4x} - 4y$ is a first-order ordinary differential equation as it fits the form $\frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y = q(x)$.

---

1. Calculate the integrating factor.

   $u(x) = e^{\int p(x) dx} = e^{\int 4 dx} = e^{4x}$
2. Evaluate using this [identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/First-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html):

   $y = \frac{1}{u(x)} \int u(x)q(x) dx$

   $  = \frac{1}{e^{4x}} \int e^{4x} x^2e^{-4x} dx $

   $  = \frac{1}{e^{4x}} \int x^2 dx $

   $  = \frac{1}{e^{4x}} (\frac{1}{3} x^3  + C)$

---

Alternatively, you can find an **exact** first-order equation of the original ODE with your integrating factor and solve from there.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2e^{-4x} - 4y$

$dy = (x^2e^{-4x} - 4y)dx$

$(x^2e^{-4x} - 4y)dx - 1dy = 0$

1. Obtain your integrating factor. For the differential equation $M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$, the integrating factor is equal to $e^{\int h(x) dx}$ where

   $h(x) = \frac{1}{N(x,y)} [M_y(x,y) - N_x(x,y)]$
2. Multiply your ODE by the integrating factor.

   $e^{4x}[(x^2e^{-4x} - 4y)dx - 1dy = 0]$

   $(x^2 - 4e^{4x}y)dx - e^{4x}dy = 0$
3. Now integrate one of the partial derivatives.

   $\int(x^2 - 4e^{4x}y)dx = \frac{1}{3}x^3 - e^{4x}y + g(y) = C$
4. To find $g(y)$ – or $g(x)$ if you integrated $N(x,y) dy$ – take the partial derivative in respect to y and set it equal to $N(x,y) dy$.

   $\frac{d}{dy} (\frac{1}{3}x^3 - e^{4x}y + g(y)) = $

   $-1 + g'(y) = -1 $

   $g'(y) = 0$

   $g(y) = \int g'(y) dy = C$
5. Plug back g(y) for your general solution.

   $\frac{1}{3}x^3 - e^{4x}y = C$

---

Note: I'm self-studying differential equations, but for the most part everything seems correct. Sorry if there's confusion.